# How do I constrain a UIStackView to the center of its parent view?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

The goal is to get two stack views side by side horizontally, the left one contained to the left and center, the right one constrained to the right and center, so that they automatically resize on each size device but still maintain the center border b/w each other (using interface builder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want one subview to fill the left half of the superview, and the other subview to fill the right half of the superview.

Constrain the left subview's top, leading, and bottom to the superview. Constrain the right subview's top, trailing, and bottom to the superview. Constrain the left subview's trailing to the right subview's leading. Constrain the widths of the subviews to be equal.

#### Left subview's constraints

[image: left subview constraints]

#### Right subview's constraints

[image: right subview constraints]

Answer (score 1):

alternative:use a horizontal stackView to contain your two sub stackViews.[image]

Comment: Note that you need to constrain the horizontal stack view to its superview's edges and you need to set its distribution to “Fill Equally”.